# Keep checkbox and label on same line (html)

Tags: html

I am trying to create a small UI for my server and I cannot get my label and checkbox to appear on the same line. I have tried several other threads but they do not work.
http://pastebin.com/0pSk6Niv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the **CSS** to

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  /*display:none;*/
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span{
  display:inline-block;  /*SET TO DISPLAY INLINE BLOCK*/
  width:36px;
  height:36px;
  margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:url(components_switches_check3.png) bottom no-repeat;
}
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `display:inline-block;` property to have an element(for your case the check box) to take up the space its content occupies.